# I need to all users and for each user all tokens in sequelize

Tags: mariadb, sequelize.js

I have a schema in sequelize that a user has many tokens, I need to get all users and for each user, I need to have all tokens. The id of user is saved in Token table as FK.

 I created this below but did not work

```
await Model.Users.findAll({
        attributes: ['id'],
        include: [
            {
                model:Model.Token,
                attributes: ['token']
            }
        ]
    });
```

The response I want to have back is like below

```
[ 
    { id: 2, Tokens: [{token: sdasdasdasdweqrewrfwe}, {token: test}] },
    { id: 6, Tokens: [{token: test2}, {token: test3}] },
    .
    .
]
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you created an association between `User` and `Token`?

Comment: Yes, the problem is that this does not get the tokens of user, it gets some that are not null but not correct one

Comment: I request you to share query generated by Sequelize from console

Comment: Thanks for commenting, it was my problem on connection, instead of connecting with userId I connected with another FK in token table. I appreciate your help, thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome, Glad to know that your problem is resolved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was not in code but in sequelize table connection, if you have same problem please check the connection

```
db.User.hasMany(db.Token, {
  onDelete: "CASCADE",
  onUpdate: "CASCADE",
  foreignKey: 'user_id'
});
```